# badge en un select para mostrar un contador

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5, ajax

Busco la manera de desplegar un listado que contenga la cantidad de estudiantes por salón es decir:

Ej:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" name="selecgrupo" id="selecgrupo">
     <option>Seleccione Grupo</option>
   </select>
</div>
<br>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'list_group',
    type: 'POST',
})
.done(function(answer)
{
    var result = $.parseJSON(answer);

    for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {                   
        $("#selecgrupo").append("<option value='" + result[i].id_grupo+ "'>" + result[i].grupo +  "</option>");
    }
})      
.fail(function(){
    console.log("error");
});
```

**PHP**

Retorna en JSON el **answer** y con append listo el id y el grupo y en HTML muestro esa lista...

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function list_group(){
   $response = $this->list_group_model->list_group();
   echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public function list_group(){
   $sql= $this->db->conn_id->execute("
     SELECT id_group, group
     FROM grupos
     ORDER BY group DESC");   

   return $sql;
}
```

**Ej:**

```
GRUPO A
GRUPO B
GRUPO C
```

Se necesita listar ese lista con la cantidad de estudiantes:
**Ej:**

```
GRUPO A      20
GRUPO B      11
GRUPO C      30
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir que te devuelve el JSON?

Comment: Hola @Daniel, estás quitando todo el rato las ediciones que estoy realizando sobre tu código. Le estoy dando formato para que los usuarios lo puedan ver mejor.

Comment: trato de hacer que quede lo mejor entendible

Comment: Si quieres que el código se vea en la pregunta final, lo que puedes hacer es seleccionar el código en cuestión y darle a Cntrl+K. De esta manera se formaterá tu código.

Comment: ok..en el append..es result[i].id_group y result[i].group no en español ya que el modelo esta en ingles los valores tomados de la base de datos

Comment: ¿Y de donde te tiene que recuperar el número de estudiantes?

Comment: esa es la cuestion...ya que deberia de hallar la forma de traer junto con el php un SELECT COUNT por cada grupo. y hacer un inner join con los estudiantes que estan relacionados con el grupo

Comment: y que se muestre ese COUNT en cada valor que arroja el select....GRUPO A 11, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es algo como lo siguiente: (Ejecutar el código para visualizar)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>50</span> GRUPO A ">GRUPO A</option>
  <option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>20</span> GRUPO B ">GRUPO B</option>
  <option data-content="<span class='label label-success'>30</span> GRUPO C ">GRUPO C</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

> **PHP**

Cambiar la consulta que tienes en el Modelo para que retorne también la cantidad de estudiantes por grupo, ej.

```
SELECT grupos.id_group, grupos.group, COUNT(estudiantes.id_estudienta) cant 
FROM grupos INNER JOIN estudiantes ON grupos.id_group = estudiantes.id_group 
GROUP BY grupos.id_group, grupos.group 
ORDER BY group DESC
```

> **HTML**

Incluir además del bootstrap la siguiente librería extendida para selects http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

> **javascript**

Tu JavaScript debería quedar parecido a lo siguientes:

```
for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{                   
   $("#selecgrupo").append("<option value='" + result[i].id_grupo+ "' data-content='<span class=\"label label-success\">" + result[i].cant + "</span> " + result[i].grupo + " '>" + result[i].grupo +  "</option>");
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes 3 tablas:

- Groups
- Students
- Group_study

Puedes hacer un group by y un join para traer la cantidad de estudiantes. Por ejemplo:

```
select sg.group_id, g.name, count(s.student_id) as 'cant'
  from study_group sg
inner join groups g on sg.group_id = g.group_id
inner join students s on sg.student_id = s.student_id
group by sg.group_id, g.name order by g.name asc;
```

Y en JS:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'list_group',
  type: 'POST'
})
.done(groups => {
  groups.forEach(function (group) {
    $('#selecgrupo').append(
      `<option value="${group.group_id}">${group.grupo} - (${group.cantidad})</option>`
    );
  });
});
```

Te renderizará algo como:

```
<option value="a294d">Grupo 1 - (45)</option>
```

Puedes ver [éste sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39d06d/6) para que lo pruebes.

Comment: muchas gracias tu comentario fue de mucha ayuda

Comment: De nada. Recuerda votar y/o marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta.